# Create an App that interact with SQL

Tags: android, ios, sql, sql-server

I've been getting my hands on apps for a few time now, and I now want to develop an App which will help user manage events. Here's the problem, I have very few knowledge in servers/DB and such.

To allow users to log in (and import friends) I count on Facebook API. But I have to manage events and users attending events (and other things but here are the main points).

Is an SQL Server sufficient (and secure) to do such things ? In the DB I plan to store only events and users attending to such events.

If yes, what kind of offer from web hosting companies would allow me to set up such databases (Dedicated SQL server ? Web hosting with output in XML/JSON ?)

If no, what method would be better.

Thank you very much for the answers and time.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server can do it.  So can any other database, SQL or NoSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Choice of database.** 
Any database can do it, but you need to know that some of them are really expensive, such as SQL Server. You can see the SQL Server pricing [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/sql-server/purchasing.aspx). I'd recommend you [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) database if your business is not really big. It is 100% free and you can find it at most of the web hosting provider.

**JSON/XML output**. This is managed by your web-service. Web-service is the server-side application, it provides information to your app, which is the client-side. You can use many technologies the do it, such as Java, PHP, Node.js, Python ... Implementation is up to you. But normally, you don't communicate the database directly with apps. You need a web service.

**Hosting**. This is hard to say, it depends on the technology chosen of your web-service.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details and info! Definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if you're satisfied with it ? I can provide additional information if needed

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely possible to use a SQL server to do these things, but you might be more comfortable using something like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or other NoSQL database providers

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a look!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Amazon Web Services. They provide SDK's for Java as well as iOS platforms. https://aws.amazon.com/

Amazon Cognito includes identity provider implementation (facebook, google, amazon, developer authenticated, and so on).

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database that can handle what you're trying to do no problem.

Look here for the SDK of your choosing. https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/

You could also utilize an Amazon EC2 instance for running your web server.

Comment: i'm using Xamarin.Forms to dev but I think I'll have to implement this by myself. Thank for the answer and the amazon suggestion!